# Commerce Kickstart: How to fix duplicated order lines appearing in Commerce Backoffice?

Tags: commerce

A site running Commerce Kickstart is occasionally finding duplicated order lines appearing in 1.) Backoffice 'quick edit' view and 2.)in the pdf output found in invoices generated by Commerce Billy module.

The duplicated item is a 'ghost' and does not form part of the order, nor does it contribute to the order total. A double check of the order at admin/commerce/orders/#ordernumber/ confirms that the duplicated item should not exist.

The error is intermittent and only effects a small pre-portion of orders placed.

I am presuming that Backoffice and Commerce Billy derive their data from the same place and I am unsure what is triggering this problem.

So the question is 'what is going wrong and how do I fix it?'

Screenshot below 1.) Quick edit view 2.) Full edit display.

[image: Screenshot of Commerce Backoffice]

As can be seen the second item is a duplicate and is not included in the order total.

[image: Screenshot of Commerce Order]